# styling the browser's autofill when we enter data into the input

Tags: css, input, background

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the background becomes white when the browser autofills. What I want is like the input below, so the background is transparent.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the following properties with a `box-shadow`, just like this. Your desired background color should be there, in the box shadow. Using `transparent` won't work, but you can try setting an alpha value for `rgba`

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #0F0F0F inset !important;
}
```

You might have to use `-moz-autofill` and `ms-autofill` too if the autocomplete in Firefox and Internet Explorer also changes the background. Otherwise, the above code should work well

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the autofill style by using `:-webkit-autofill`

```
:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset;
}
```